# How do I assign a device level hotkey to my Blackberry App?

Tags: blackberry, user-controls, java-me, shortcut

Blackberry devices have shortcuts to open applications.  For example, if you hit the 'T' button, the tasks app will open.

(BTW, you have to have "Call from Home Screen" disabled in the Phone App Settings for this to work)

How can I assign a shortcut key to open my own application?

For clarity and in case the link dies, I'll post the instructions here:

Complete the following steps:

1. In your Project Properties in the Integration Development Environment (IDE), click the Resources tab.
2. Under the Title ID option, specify the Resource variable name (App_Title) which corresponds to the actual text to be displayed (myApp) on the ribbon.
3. If you want the A in myApp to be a hotkey, insert the unicode underscore character (\u0332) after the A. Therefore, in your resource package, instead of specifying myApp as the value for the variable App_Title, specify the following:

   myA\u0332pp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [knowledge base article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/How_To_-_Enable_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_an_application.html?nodeid=800822&vernum=0). Of course you have to avoid collisions with other applications.

Comment: Effin awesome!  Also, be sure to do the same thing in all languages you might have defined.  Different keys could be defined for different locales.